# Has the "ConvNeXt" family of models been removed from Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

When trying to use the ConvNeXtTiny model from Keras, I get the following error: AttributeError: module 'keras.applications' has no attribute 'ConvNeXtTiny'

```
filename = "ConvNextTiny_firstpass_model"

# layer construction
base_model = applications.ConvNeXtTiny( #preproccing included
    input_shape=(targetWidth, targetHeight, 3),
    include_top=False,
)
base_model.trainable = False

flatten_layer = layers.Flatten()
fc_layer = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')
dropout_layer = layers.Dropout(0.3) 

#layer connecting
x = flip_layer(input_layer)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = flatten_layer(x)
x = fc_layer(x)
x = dropout_layer(x)
predictions = output_layer(x)
model = keras.Model(input_layer, predictions)
```

Here are my imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras 
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
from keras import applications
from keras import losses
from keras import callbacks
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv
import csv
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
```

Possibly relevant versioning:

```
ipython==8.5.0
tensorflow==2.10.0
keras==2.10.0
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
pandas==1.4.4
numpy==1.23.3
matplotlib==3.6.0
opencv-python==4.6.0.66
sklearn==0.0
```

Comment: That looks like a missing page in the Keras documentation. The other models go through `tf.keras.applications`, and there is a [`tf.keras.applications.convnext`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/convnext/ConvNeXtTiny)

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I tried replacing applications.ConvNeXtTiny with applications.convnext.ConvNeXtTiny, as seen in the documentation, and received a similar error "AttributeError: module 'keras.applications' has no attribute 'convnext'"

Comment: I still cannot reproduce this problem. Maybe you have an old version of TensorFlow / Keras? In `tensorflow==2.10.0` it appears possible to do: `from tensorflow.keras.applications import convnext` or `from keras.applications import convnext`.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I'm using tensorflow version 2.10.0. I'll try rebooting my session in the morning, but for now I'm receiving the same error when trying both the imports you mentioned.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I'm at quiet the loss. I rebooted my session and even uninstalled and reinstalled tensorflow with the same results.

Comment: This feels like it's wandering into "environment configuration error" territory. Can you edit your question to include OS / Python / pip / package versions / install locations? (`python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.version.GIT_VERSION, tf.version.VERSION)"`). If you have `sklearn`, this utility is helpful: `python -c 'import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous imports placed above the convnext import were causing issues.

Moving `from tensorflow.keras.applications import convnext` to the top of all the imports allowed it to import properly.